# Link or image preg/ereg replace?

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, preg-replace, ereg

Heres my issue. I'm building a website where you can share links/pictures. Now heres what I want to do. If the link is a link to a site, then display a link such as:

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">http://example.com</a>
```

But heres my downfall, if it a picture(jpg, gif, png, ect) I want to display that on the page instead of the link. How do I go about doing that?

--
Forgot to add:

```
$profile_post_post = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $profile_post_post);
```

Thats the code that makes the link.

Comment: an img just uses the <img src="link/to/img.jpg" alt="" />
if you link an image you would just do <a href="link"><img src="link/to/img.jpg" alt="" /></a>

Can you elaborate more on what you already have in place?

Comment: Please share the code how you do it already for the normal link.

Comment: Blimey; I haven't seen `ereg_replace` in years! Is there any particular reason, @JakeAero, that you ignored that **massive red warning** on its manual page, stating that "this function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0", and that "relying on this feature is highly discouraged"? Or the long-standing tip at the bottom that reads "`preg_replace()`, which uses a Perl-compatible regular expression syntax, is often a faster alternative to `ereg_replace()`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_replace_callback`, providing a callback that selects the link contents conditionally based on its format. i.e. if it ends in `.jpg`, render an `img` tag. If it ends in anything other than a typical image file extension, print its name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PHP, and the URL is stored in **$url**:

```
if (!preg_match("@^https?\:\/\/@", $url)
{
    $url = "http://$url";
}

if (preg_match("@\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$@", $url))
{
   echo '<img src="' . $url . '" />"';
}
else
{
   echo '<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank">' . $url . </a>;
}
```

This is not an exact method, as some pictures may be served with the correct MIME type without bearing a gif, jpeg, jpg or png extension.

This is a far better method to check if a link refers to a picture, but it is time- and bandwith consuming. As such, it would be better to store the result in a database at the same time $url is, for later reuses:

```
if (!preg_match("@^https?\:\/\/@", $url)
{
    $url = "http://$url";
}

$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
$mime_type = isset($headers["Content-Type"])  ?  $headers["Content-Type"]  :  "";

if (preg_match("@\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$@", $url)  ||  preg_match("@^image\/@", $mime_type))
{
   $html = '<img src="' . $url . '" />"';
}
else
{
   $html = '<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank">' . $url . '</a>';
}
```